# How to assign the same value to more var in scala

Tags: scala, variables, scala-2.10, scala-2.8

To instantiate the variables can do so:

```
scala> var (a, b, c) = (0, 0, 23)
a: Int = 0
b: Int = 0
c: Int = 23
```

but if I wanted to do such a thing?

```
scala> a = b = c
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
       a = b = c
             ^
```

how can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `a = b = c` because `a` has already been defined as a `Int var`, and with the `a = b = c` statement you are giving `a` a `Unit`, 'b = c'.

When you assign a value to a variable in Scala you don't get as a result the value assigned.

In other languages `b = c` would be evaluated to 23, the value of c. In Scala `b = c` is just a `Unit`, writing `a = b = c` is exactly like writing `a = (b = c)`, hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

`var a,b,c = 0`

should do the trick.

Comment: I'm interested to know how to give the value of C to A and B

Comment: no guys.... i'm not interested to know the other ways to INSTANTIATE more var but i'm interested to know how to valorize them in one function. For example a = b = 12 but in this way does not work

Comment: you want to first set c to be 23, and a and b to be 0, and then set a and b to be the value of c? correct?